# SQL Server 2008 timeout exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, timeout

I am developing the wireless application, when I do query 2000+ rows from SQL Server 2008, the  timeout exception happens.

I am using a lot of linq in my program in a loop. When I comment some of them, it will be better but still happen.

Does Linq cause the slow performance? Is there any other reason cause this issue? And how can I solve it?

Thanks.

```
enter code here
                    var listShipUnit = from ShipUnit su in bdd.ShipUnit
                                       where (su.ShipmentID == shipmentNumber
                                        && (su.QStatus != "1" || su.QStatus == null)
                                        && (!su.CaseID.Equals(null) 
                                        && !su.CaseID.ToUpper().Equals("UNKNOWN") && 
                                        !su.CaseID.Equals(string.Empty) && 
                                        !su.CaseID.ToUpper().Equals("NULL") 
                                        && su.CaseID.Length > 0))
                                           group su by su.CaseID into gsu
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               gsu.Key,
                                               gsu,
                                               TotalWeight = gsu.Sum(w => w.Weight),
                                               TotalVolume = gsu.Sum(v => v.Volume),
                                               TotalCount = gsu.Sum(v => v.ShipUnitCount)
                                           };



                    foreach (var shipUnit in listShipUnit)
                    {
                        tempListShipUnitGroup.Add(new ShipUnitGroupSTL(shipUnit.gsu.ToList(), shipUnit.Key, shipUnit.TotalVolume.ToString(), shipUnit.TotalWeight.ToString(), shipUnit.TotalCount.ToString()));
                    }

                    List<ShipUnitGroupSTL> revShipUnitGroup = new List<ShipUnitGroupSTL>();
                    List<string> finishPallet = new List<string>();
                    List<string> finishCase = new List<string>();


                    // 2013.12.19 device null exception ---> start
                    var stlunits = bdd.ScanToLoad;
                    List<ScanToLoad> stlList = stlunits.ToList();

                    //var shipunits = bdd.ShipUnit;
                    //List<ShipUnit> shipunitList = shipunits.ToList();

                    if (stlList != null && stlList.Count() > 0)
                    // 2013.12.19 device null exception --- end
                    {
                        //// get the recently record from STL talbe
                        foreach (var shipUnitGroup in tempListShipUnitGroup)
                        {
                            string tempCaseID;
                            string tempPalletID;

                            var unit = shipUnitGroup.GroupShipUnit;


                            tempCaseID = shipUnitGroup.GroupKey;
                            tempPalletID = unit.FirstOrDefault().PalletID;

                        //    // 2013.12.19 device null exception ---> start
                        //    // look up the caseId in the STL table
                            var stlunit = stlList
                                        .Where(s => s.CaseID.Equals(tempCaseID))
                                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.UpdateDate);

                        //    //var stlunit = bdd.ScanToLoad
                        //    //            .Where(s => s.ScanToLoadID.Equals(tempCaseID)
                        //    //                || s.CaseID.Equals(tempCaseID))
                        //    //            .OrderByDescending(s => s.UpdateDate);

                        //    // 2013.12.19 device null exception ---> end



                            if (stlunit != null && stlunit.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                string stlPallet = null;

                                stlPallet = stlunit.FirstOrDefault().NewPalletID;

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stlPallet))
                                {
                                    if (tempPalletID.Equals(stlPallet))
                                    {
                                        finalListShipUnitGroup.Add(shipUnitGroup);
                                        //continue;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var revShipUnit = bdd.ShipUnit
                                                    .Where(su => su.ShipmentID == shipmentNumber
                                                        && (su.QStatus != "1" || su.QStatus == null)
                                                        && su.PalletID.Equals(stlPallet));

                                        if (revShipUnit != null && revShipUnit.Count() > 0)
                                        {
                                            unit.FirstOrDefault().PalletID = stlPallet;
                                            finalListShipUnitGroup.Add(shipUnitGroup);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    finalListShipUnitGroup.Add(shipUnitGroup);
                                    //continue;
                                }


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                finalListShipUnitGroup.Add(shipUnitGroup);
                                //continue;
                             }

                            finishCase.Add(tempCaseID);
                            var checkFinshPallet = finishPallet
                                                    .Contains(tempPalletID);

                            if (checkFinshPallet)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            finishPallet.Add(tempPalletID);

                        }


                        foreach (var tempPalletID in finishPallet)
                        {
                            // look up the pallet in the STL table, add others new caseId in STL table
                            var stlunitPal = stlList
                                        .Where(s => s.NewPalletID.Equals(tempPalletID))
                                        .OrderByDescending(s => s.UpdateDate);

                            if (stlunitPal != null && stlunitPal.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                //IEnumerable<MobilePlusServer.ShipUnit> newCaseList;
                                string stlPalletID;

                                // add and remove case from the Pallet
                                foreach (var s in stlunitPal)
                                {
                                    stlPalletID = s.NewPalletID;

                                    //var addSus = from ShipUnit su in bdd.ShipUnit
                                    //             where (su.CaseID.Equals(s.CaseID) && su.RecordID.Equals(s.CaseRecordID))
                                    //                    && (su.QStatus != "1" || su.QStatus == null)
                                    //             group su by su.CaseID into gsu
                                    //             select new
                                    //             {
                                    //                 gsu.Key,
                                    //                 gsu,
                                    //                 TotalWeight = gsu.Sum(w => w.Weight),
                                    //                 TotalVolume = gsu.Sum(v => v.Volume),
                                    //                 TotalCount = gsu.Sum(v => v.ShipUnitCount)
                                    //             };

                                    var addSus = from ShipUnit su in bdd.ShipUnit
                                                 where (su.CaseID.Equals(s.CaseID) && su.RecordID.Equals(s.CaseRecordID)
                                                     && (su.QStatus != "1" || su.QStatus == null))
                                                 select su;


                                    if (addSus != null && addSus.Count() > 0)
                                    {
                                        var addSu = addSus.FirstOrDefault();

                                        // get the remove pallet id
                                        string adShipmentID = addSu.ShipmentID;
                                        string adPalletID = addSu.PalletID;
                                        //string adRecordID = unit.FirstOrDefault().RecordID.ToString();
                                        //string adCaseID = unit.FirstOrDefault().RecordID.ToString();
                                        if (!shipmentNumber.Equals(adShipmentID)
                                            && !finishCase.Contains(s.CaseID))
                                        {
                                            // set new pallet id
                                            addSu.PalletID = stlPalletID;

                                            finalListShipUnitGroup.Add(new ShipUnitGroupSTL(
                                                addSus.ToList(),
                                                s.CaseID,
                                                addSu.Volume.ToString(),
                                                addSu.Weight.ToString(),
                                                addSu.ShipUnitCount.ToString()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // 2013.12.19 device null exception ---> start
                    else
                    {
                        finalListShipUnitGroup = tempListShipUnitGroup;
                    }
```

Comment: Linq is a layer that slows things down a bit, but this is not your problem.  Post the code/query that you are using and it will be a lot easier to answer this question.

Comment: **Show us something!** we can't see your screen, nor read your mind - you'll have to **show us** what you're doing. What do your tables look like, what queries do you run against them? Do you have any indexes on those tables - and if yes, **what** indexes? How many rows are there in the table, how many do you read with your queries?

Comment: @paqogomez linq shouldn't be slowing things down particularly unless the query evaluation is forced and then queried further (e.g. `myquery.ToList().Where(x => x.Thing == MatchingThing)`).

Comment: @adhocgeek my comment was simply that linq is an abstraction layer, so inherently slows things down in comparison to raw sql.  The difference in practical terms however is negligible and is obviously not Eric's problem

Comment: @paqogomez that rather depends on how the linq is being used and what you mean by raw sql. It's not inherently slower than, say, constructing dynamic SQL. Expression trees give you a more fluent way of defining that kind of thing IMO and the output can still be the same as if you'd handcrafted the SQL yourself.

Comment: @adhocgeek I was in no way disparaging Linq.  This is not the place for a linq discussion, its the place to get Eric's question answered.

Comment: That's not my point - saying "Linq is a layer that slows things down a bit" is misleading. It's like saying "C# is an interpreted language so it's bound to be slow". IMO this is the kind of response you should be wary of giving to a new poster, even in comments.

Comment: Thanks all. here is the code

Comment: It is long code. I got it from other people left my inc. I do not know how to paste here.

Comment: More than likely it is because you are looping instead of using set-based logic. It is a VERY poor practice to loop through database records.

Comment: Thanks. HLGEM. I know you points. But the thing is that it is no time to rewrite the original logic of taking the linq out of the loop

Comment: The logic is like that group from the table[I],
then linq is called in the loop of the list to query the table[II].
Let's say 1000 reords in the list from table[I].

There is a part of the logic of the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Indexing on SQL for getting faster queries 
I recommend use index on your joining fields

see this documentations [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39006/Overview-of-SQL-Server-2005-2008-Table-Indexing-Pa) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964714%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fp5_iXhP_0)

Answer (score 0):

Having such complicated queries, could easily be interpreted as an indication of poor design (either in the queries or in the database). I would suggest breaking your queries to smaller ones and then compose them. This would lead you to clearer code and logic. Then you could use the [SQL server profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see the exact sql queries executed, and see if the delay is due to the translation between Linq to Entities and SQL. If you are certain that you could not make your queries simpler, then you could use [indexing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095.aspx) on the level of SQL Server

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks. Pantelis. It is really poor design, and so many complicated Linq. I think it is the reason. I will try add the index